# Azure yaml release pipeline pass parameter value from prompt

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I wanted to know is there any way where I can get ask through UI prompt for my dynamic generated parameter value which I can enter each time I run the release pipeline.

I read with parameters and variables with their default values but no pop up is coming where I can enter the dynamic parameter value.

The pop I am looking for is the same as we do get for person approval in the pipeline, so I can give my desire dynamic value and use it as variable in the pipeline further.

Hope some can help me with this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Note: Dynamic parameter means for each pipeline what would be different if not then I could have used azure variable instead.

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the following workarounds helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 2):

For YAML pipeline with parameters, you could specify value in Run Pipeline window when run it.

```
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  type: string
  default: ubuntu-latest
  values:
  - windows-latest
  - vs2017-win2016
  - ubuntu-latest
  - ubuntu-16.04
  - macOS-latest
  - macOS-10.14

trigger: none

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.image }}
```

[image: //]

More information: [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)

Answer (score 1):

In YAML pipelines you can add a variable and let the users override him when the run the pipeline.

When you edit the YAML click on "Variables":

[image]

When you add a new variable or edit an existing one, check the checkbox "**Let users override this value when running this pipelin**e".

[image]

Now, when you run the pipeline, in the **Advanced options** click on **Variables**, enter the variable you want to change, and replace the value.

[image]

Comment: Will this can be done on release yml base pipeline too?

Comment: @YouAreAwesome Yes :) the screenshot is from YAML pipelines. go to Azure DevOps -> pipelines, enter your yaml and in top right corner click on "Variables".